# How to make a footer that stays on the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I need a footer that stays on the bottom of the page when there is no content but when there is content it gets pushed down so the content can fit how do I do that.

```css
.credits {
  background: rgb(207, 207, 207);
  padding: 10px 15px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50vh;
  float: bottom;
}

#author {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- The Container containing the list for styling purposes -->
<div class="listContainer">
  <ul class="todoList"></ul>
</div>
<!-- Credits -->
<footer class="credits">
  <hr /> &copy; copyright reserved<br /><br />made by
  <span id="author">someone</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: Change the position to fixed or absolute.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .credits {
      background: rgb(207, 207, 207);
      padding: 10px 15px 15px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 110px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    #author {
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
    }


<!-- end snippet -->